# The value for annotation attribute ApiOperation.notes must be a constant expression

Tags: java, swagger

I am trying to generate a sample json from a class and assign the string to ApiOperation.notes, but it keeps giving me an error stating "The value for annotation attribute ApiOperation.notes must be a constant expression."

Is there a way to resolve this?

```
@ApiOperation(
    value = "Get a content type by its name",
    notes = Helper.generateSampleJson(SomeClass.class),
    response = classOf[models.ContentType],
  )

class Helper {

    public static String generateSampleJson(Class c){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can resolve it by using constant expressions. What you have in your annotation are not constant expressions.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, by calling `toJson` on a `Class` object?